# choose different data types in struct array

Tags: c

I use a struct like this millions of times in a program

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int a, b, c;
} B_STRUCT;
```

and then I build the struct into a very large array, like this:

```
HUGE_ARRAY_STRUCT[2][191914131].a = 234;
HUGE_ARRAY_STRUCT[2][191914131].b = 232;
```

about 99.9% percent of the data in question is much less than the unsigned short int size, but use unsigned int to be safe.  While this sounds like a trivial issue, sometimes the difference is ***several GB*** in RAM.

Is there a way I can use the struct above if the integers are > than the unsigned short int max, and the struct below if they are below the unsigned short int max?

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned short int b, c;
} SMALLER_STRUCT;
```

But can I build HUGE_ARRAY_STRUCT with one data type in one case, and another data type in another case, in the same struct array?

Comment: If you have a data structure so large (which I doubt), surely a database is of order

Comment: `if(x > USHRT_MAX) B_STRUCT.b = x; else C_STRUCT.b = x;`

Comment: Your question is too general to give you useful information.  *Of course* it is possible to do as you ask in the abstract, but whether there is such an approach that you can usefully apply to your program is a different question.  The answer to *that* question depends on details of how you use the current, larger `struct`.

Comment: Riley, I probably should have clarified, I want to use something more like

`typedef struct {
    unsigned int a;
 if (x < USHRT_MAX) {
    unsigned short int b, c;
} else {
   int b, c;
}
} B_STRUCT;`

Comment: The code shown does not show how the application that causes "several GB in RAM.".  To get better answers, detail how the data is used, preferable with existing code.